# Jenkins build not working - package installed but not detected in Reference for ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, log4net

I am creating CICD setup for ASP.Net MVC project in Jenkins. Jenkins build fails due missing package in project. but when I logged in Build server machine (Jenkins) and checked package in packages folder, it is present and other packages are also present. I then explored solution in Visual Studio 2017 and found that missing package is not detected in Reference. I re-builded solution but still it is not detecting package.

Package is - log4net library

I have below settings in .csproj but no luck.

```
 <Reference Include="log4net, Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>packages\log4net.2.0.5\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
```

Project is compiling properly on my machine but not on Jenkins Build Machine. I also cleared nuget cache from Jenkins Build machine but no luck.

Comment: Can you confirm whether nuget restore is being run?

Comment: Yes @AntonyKoch. nuget restore is used and it is working with no issues. I have build step after nuget restore.

Comment: Any updates? Why Jenkins build fails in spite of it contains all packages installed and compiling properly on local machine.

Comment: Have you considered the working directory might be wrong, meaning "./packages" doesn't exist?

Comment: I deleted package folder and removed all references and again added all references. it worked. It could be .csproj issue.